# ftp_connect do not work for some hosts

Tags: php, ftp

ftp_connect function is not working for some hosts, whereas if I connect it by ftp software it is working.
while it do well for other websites.

what could be the possible reason ?
or is there any other better way to connect to ftp to copy and delete files.

Comment: Can you show us your code?  What exactly is the error?  What shows up in your error log?

Answer (score 1):

You may be having problems with requirements for "passive FTP".  Check out PHP's [ftp_pasv()](http://php.net/ftp_pasv) function.

Remember also that FTP is an ancient, insecure protocol.  It predates most of the Internet, and can be finicky to get working in complex network environments.  If you can switch to [SFTP](http://ir.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php) or [SCP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-recv.php), or even [WebDAV](http://code.google.com/p/sabredav/wiki/WebDAVClient) over HTTPS, you'll likely be better off.